# How do I clear an array at the end of a do-while loop in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, do-while

The purpose of my function is to generate 8 random letters n times (specified when it is compiled). I approached this by writing two functions called `genNumbers` - which generates 8 random numbers (between 0 and 25) and places them into an array called `numbers`, and `convert` - which converts each number in the array to the corresponding letter in the alphabet and places those letters into an array called `letters`. Those two functions work perfectly, I tested them out multiple times.

Now I am having trouble implementing them in main.

I want main to take in a parameter which specifies how many `letters` arrays are desired. So for example calling `a.out 3` would output something like

```
SAFJPONG   1
VYREMNXZ   2
QWMKUZXC   3
```

This is what I have in my main:

```
int numbers[8];
string letters[8];

void genNumbers() {
int i;

srand (time(NULL));

for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    numbers[i] = rand() % 25;
}
}

void convert() {
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] == 0) {
        letters[i] = "A";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 1) {
        letters[i] = "B";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 2) {
        letters[i] = "C";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 3) {
        letters[i] = "D";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 4) {
        letters[i] = "E";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 5) {
        letters[i] = "F";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 6) {
        letters[i] = "G";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 7) {
        letters[i] = "H";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 8) {
        letters[i] = "I";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 9) {
        letters[i] = "J";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 10) {
        letters[i] = "K";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 11) {
        letters[i] = "L";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 12) {
        letters[i] = "M";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 13) {
        letters[i] = "N";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 14) {
        letters[i] = "O";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 15) {
        letters[i] = "P";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 16) {
        letters[i] = "Q";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 17) {
        letters[i] = "R";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 18) {
        letters[i] = "S";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 19) {
        letters[i] = "T";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 20) {
        letters[i] = "U";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 21) {
        letters[i] = "V";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 22) {
        letters[i] = "W";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 23) {
        letters[i] = "X";
    }
    else if (numbers[i] == 24) {
        letters[i] = "Y";
    }
    else {
        letters[i] = "Z";
    }
}
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
 int i = 0;
 int g,n;

if (argc == 2 && argv[1][0] > 0) {
    n = atoi(argv[1]);

    do {
        genNumbers();
        convert();
        for (g = 0; g < 8; g++) {
            cout << letters[g];     // this is where I believe the problem is
        }
        cout << "   " << i+1 << endl;
        i++;
    }
    while (i < n);
}

return 0;
}
```

When I run `a.out 3`, my output looks like:

```
SAFJPONG   1
SAFJPONG   2
SAFJPONG   3
```

So evidently, my main is returning the same `letters` array every time, and not creating 3 different ones like I want it to.

I have commented where I believe my problem is arising. I feel like it has something to do with having to delete the array so that a new one is made every time. Can anyone spot where I am going wrong?

Comment: Can you show the implementation of your `genNumbers` and `convert` functions?  Based off what I see here it looks like you are having both modify global variables.  Is that true?  And why?  This is likely not your ideal situation

Comment: `generate 8 random letters` Let me guess, you are calling `srand` at the beginning of `genNumbers`, or not calling it at all.

Comment: You don't have an srand() call in your main. I assume you're calling it repeatedly in your genNumbers function?

Comment: Looking at your source, the only difference is uupposed to be the `n = atoi(argv[1]);` instead of a constant, is that right?

Comment: @sedavidw , I added the implementations of genNumbers and convert in the original post

Comment: Instead of 26 if...then try `letters[i] = 'A' + numbers[i];`

Comment: @user657267 yeah that's right, I have srand in genNumbers. I have added its implementation to make things clearer.

Comment: Use standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)

Comment: @JonathanPotter I see. Thanks. Much cleaner. It's still producing the same `letters` array every time though. Any idea why?

Comment: srand(time(NULL)) intializes the random number generator based on the current time in seconds. The seconds most likely won't have changed in between calls so you will get the same number. Just call it once when the program starts

Comment: @cursayer try defining `srand (time(NULL));` once instead of everytime the function is called

Comment: @samgak Ahh that makes perfect sense. Never knew that. Thank you!!!

Comment: or just do [something like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e9f0fa4536380aa).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I implemented the same program. I think there is something fishy with the second line in your code `string letters[8];`. Also you may want to check your `genNumbers` and `convert` functions.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int nums[8];
char letters[9];

void genNumbers() {
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
        nums[i] = rand()%26;
}

void convert() {
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
        letters[i] = 'A' + nums[i];
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    letters[8] = '\0';
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n = 0;
    if (argc == 2) {
        n = atoi(argv[1]);
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            genNumbers();
            convert();
            printf("%s\n", letters);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

You are going wrong in your call to `srand(time(NULL))` in the `genNumbers` function. Calling it every time when you make a call to `genNumbers` causes you to reset the seed thus restarting the pseudo-random number sequence. It gives the same number even though you use time as a seed because the execution of this code is quick and the time difference is negligible. Your code would work if you had a call to something like `usleep(1000000);` in your code as it would cause significant time different between the function calls. For example: This code yields the desired result:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int nums[8];
char letters[9];

void genNumbers() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
        nums[i] = rand()%26;
}

void convert() {
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
        letters[i] = 'A' + nums[i];
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    letters[8] = '\0';
    int n = 0;
    if (argc == 2) {
        n = atoi(argv[1]);
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            genNumbers();
            convert();
            printf("%s\n", letters);
            usleep(1000000);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you still want to avoid the call to `srand()` in main then here's something you can do in `genNumbers` itself:

```
void genNumbers() {
    srand(time(NULL)*rand()); // notice time(NULL)*rand()
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
        nums[i] = rand()%26;
}
```